# What is a good introduction to cluster algebras from surfaces?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cluster-algebras

What is a good reference for cluster algebras from surfaces, with a view to their connection to Teichmuller theory?

In my view, that means it should start off with unpunctured surfaces (and in fact, it would be fine with me if it never went further).

So far as I understand, this means that the results involved might well predate the invention of cluster algebras, but I still think that it would be nice to have an exposition of them from a cluster algebras perspective.  I am hoping someone else agrees (and has consequently been inspired to write something along these lines).

My ideal answer (while I'm dreaming) would not assume familiarity with cluster algebras, and as little knowledge of Teichmuller theory as possible.

Comment: I am so looking for a nice readable introduction to precisely the other half of cluster algebra theory (the algebraic and combinatorial parts). But on the geometric side, I have been recommended Gekhtman, Shapiro, Vainstein (the AMS book, not the arXiv paper) -- or is it yet *another* geometric component of cluster algebra theory? (NB: I have no idea about geometry.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Gekhtman-Shapiro-Vainshtein takes a Poisson geometry approach, which is great, but I would like something more direct if possible.  (Though maybe what I want can be found in there.)  If you post a more specific question about "the algebraic and combinatorial parts", I may be able to help.  Have you seen the notes from Fomin's Park City course, written up by Nathan Reading (arXiv:math/0505518)?

Comment: I know of them, though I'd like something with proofs. Thanks for reminding me of them, though.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809003387  ?

Comment: I don't know if this helps Hugh, but @darijgrinberg you might like Ralf Schiffler's new book, "Quiver Representations" (Springer).  It's not explictly cluster-y but does cover the combinatorial realisation of types A and D by triangulations of polygons, for example, by relating it to the cluster category.  Its style is "algebraic and combinatorial", for sure.

Comment: Looking through my folder of cluster algebra notes, I did also spot some notes of Schiffler from a meeting in Sao Pedro (put "schiffler sao pedro" in your favourite search engine).  Lecture 4 is an short intro to cluster algebras from surfaces.

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to know whether you're looking for something alternative to the canonical starting point of the Fomin-Shapiro-Thurston paper?  [I'm certain you and the other contributors above know of this - I'm just naming it explicitly "for the record", for non-experts finding their way here.]

Comment: All suggestions are welcome, but in the interests of clarifying my question, I'll explain why Tom and Jan's suggestions aren't quite what I'm looking for.  Tom's suggestion (a paper by Schiffler) doesn't have any Teichmuller theory at all, and what I really want is a straightforward explanation of the link to Teichmuller theory (interpreting cluster variables as lambda-lengths, etc.).  Jan's suggestion (plus its sequel by Fomin-Thurston) are canonical sources, but I was hoping for something easier for a student to read, and which devotes less of its energy to the punctured case.

Comment: I see, thanks. But now I don't have any suggestions left  to offer :-(

Comment: @JanGrabowski, thanks for pointing out Schiffler's notes, which I was unfamiliar with, and which may come in handy (but for the same reason as for the Schiffler paper Tom suggested, are not really what this question is asking for).

Comment: You've, of course, checked out the two intros by L. Williams and B. Keller. Have you reviewed these lectures https://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/CA.html ?

Comment: @TomCopeland Thank you for reminding me about Lauren's notes, http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6263 ! They seem to cover exactly what I wanted.  If you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'll leave it open, if you don't mind, to encourage someone to find another good paper.

Comment: I should point out the canonical source for sources on cluster algebras: Fomin's "Cluster algebras portal", http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~fomin/cluster.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Belatedly, per comments: Lauren Williams gave a [survey course](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewilliams/CA.html) with recorded lectures, referencing her paper "[Cluster algebras: an introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6263)."

More recently: [Introduction to Cluster Algebras: Chapter 6](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09189) (2020)

Some background/motivational material:

"[The Positive Grassmannian
(from a mathematician’s perspective)](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lmason/NGSA14/Slides/Lauren-Williams.pdf)" slides by Williams

"[Combinatorics of KP solitons from the real grassmannian](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ewilliams/papers/KW-Abel-May4.pdf)" by Kodama and Williams

[KP solitons, total positivity, and cluster algebras](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/island/island4/Programme_files/talks/williams.pdf)" presentation slides by Williams

"[A mathematician's unanticipated journey through the physical world](https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-mathematicians-adventure-through-the-physical-world-20201216/?fbclid=IwAR0N0iUyqeHwUtk5Y0LzffHY5uwCBbqSRFD_gvxtZNQP3ctCHeePh3NX1ow)," a popularizing article by Hartnett article in Quantamagazine on Williams and her work.

Comment: (Worth noting that this question is quite old and by now Hugh has probably learned what he wanted to about cluster algebras from surfaces.) These notes of Ralph Schiffler, about cluster algebras from surfaces in particular, look nice: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.le-meur/CIMPA/Course-Schiffler.pdf

Comment: Motivational: See allusions to cluster algebras in the body and comments to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184803/guises-of-the-stasheff-polytopes-associahedra-for-the-coxeter-a-n-root-system

Comment: Related MO-Q: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108797/what-do-cluster-algebras-tell-us-about-grassmannians